# How does SC-FDE modifies $E_b$ (in AWGN function)

Tags: fft, noise, frequency

In lot of matlab scripts of SC-FDE simulations I see $E_b = N$ (being $N$ the length of the block to be transmitted through the channel and Eb energy per bit) to generate the AWGN. I would like to understand why is that, and more specifically:
Assuming, instead of a block length $N$, I have 2 sequences length $N/2$. I FFT() each one, concatenate the frequency-domain sequences and send the result (of length $N$) through the channel. What would my $E_b$ in AWGN function be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here $E_b=N$ means $N$ pulses (i.e. PHY waveforms) of unit energy represent one *information* bit.
I suppose it is due to the S/P (serial to parallel) block that translates each bit of information to a vector of size $N$. So it is implicitly assumed that the energy of each component of the vector is one.

Regarding your second question, you should consider the number of information bits. If you have *one* bit of information to generate the two vectors of size $N/2$, then again $E_b=\frac{N/2+N/2}{1}=N$.

Comment: I am glad it helped.